# Copy lib assets to target dirctory with ng-packagr (Angular library)

Tags: angular, angular-library, ng-packagr

with the new version of ng-packagr (9.0.1+) it is possible to copy assets from an Angular library into the dist folder.

See also:
https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/copy-assets.md

So far it works. However, I currently have the problem that I cannot determine the target directory in the dist folder. Is this even possible in ng-packagr?

My configuration looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/...",
  "assets": [
    "./src/lib/assets"
  ],
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the destination path is exactly as the source path, going under "dist", so in your case will be

```
/dist/src/lib/assets
```